# How to draw rounded corner in adobe illustrator shown in the example below?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image: MY ATTEMPT TO MAKE IT COMPLETEstrong text]

[image: calendar]

After many attempts, I failed to make the folded corner of the calendar. May I ask please how to make my incomplete calendar icon?

The attempt was to solve using the rectangle tool.

Comment: What have you tried, and why aren't you happy with the results? If you tell us of your previous attempts, we will be able to help you way faster and better.

Comment: @Vincent, thank you for your comment. The GIF shows my attempt to solve the right hand corner of the calendar.

Comment: Use shape builder.

Answer (score 3):

Clip a piece of the underlying object with a 45 degrees tilted line (hold shift as you draw to snap to 45 degrees). Use Object > Path > Divide Objects Below. Release the piece by applying Object > Path > Compound path > Release and Ungroup if there's many. Rotate the separated piece 180 degrees.

[image]

ADD due the comments

There's no need to ungroup nor release compound paths if the splitted shape is created with no tricks as single simple closed path. Division with a line creates  two separately selectable and editable pieces. In the next image at step 2 the smaller piece is colored to blue:

[image]

The division line was not tilted 45 degrees, but 180 degrees rotation still creates a fitting result (=3).

Unfortunately the result is physically wrong. User @joojaa has commented that fact. You must create a mirrored version. One way to do it is to apply Object > Transform > Reflect > Vertical to the smaller piece (=4)

In step 5 the piece is moved. Learn to use Smart Guides and Snap to Point for perfect placing. Set them ON in the view menu. Select the piece. Hold Ctrl to get the direct selection tool temporarily ON and drag the rightmost anchor point to X.Be sure that nothing else is selected nor touched because in that case the direct selection tool destroys your shape. If not sure, deselect all and select the corner piece.

6. Select the piece, click the rotation tool , click point X to define the rotation center and rotate the piece. It should snap exactly. This is the mirrored version which is physically possible.

A short way to mirror is to use the Reflect tool. You simply select the shape to be mirrored, click the Reflect tool (it's under the rotate tool) and click the endpoints of the mirroring line.

Comment: Or mirror along parting line if the shape isnt symmetric.

Comment: @user287001, not able to find the second option called *compund path* .  May I ask please how to deal with it?

Comment: @joojaa, could not able to grasp the mirroring concept. Could you please elaborate it?

Comment: @python the formation of a compound path was my  error. The shape happened to become  a compound path due the idiotic drawing order. If the line clips the corner properly  to a separately selectable object without a need to release anything you only have worked in a rational way.

Comment: @user287001, thanks for your reply. somehow, I managed to complete the shape, but the curved line thickness is much more thicker  than the other border.